# Thingsboard draw line on map not a polygon

Tags: thingsboard

I want to know how to draw lines on the map using custom widget in Thingsboard. Is there anyone who tried to modified inside using javascript?

how to do it here

```
self.onInit = function() {
    self.ctx.map = new TbMapWidgetV2('openstreet-map', false, self.ctx);
     


}

self.onDataUpdated = function() {
        
    self.ctx.map.update();
    
}

self.onResize = function() {
    self.ctx.map.resize();
}

self.actionSources = function() {
    return TbMapWidgetV2.actionSources();
}

self.onDestroy = function() {
    self.ctx.map.destroy();
}

self.typeParameters = function() {
    return {
        hasDataPageLink: true
    };
}
```

Where should I put this?

```
//where should i put this?

var lineCoordinates = [
  { lat: 37.774929, lng: -122.419418 },  // Start point
  { lat: 37.804996, lng: -122.407547 }   // End point
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the default map widgets as the basis for a custom widget. You have to create the custom widget completely from scratch.

But drawing of lines is also possible without having to develop your own widget. This works out-of-the-box with default map widgets:

Widget Configuration:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Attribute:

```
[
  [
    5.04409280561122,
    10.892496518385302
  ],
  [
    5.048902066863962,
    10.899666269572215
  ],
  [
    5.0494364270244905,
    10.900417590804363
  ]
]
```

Find more details here:
https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6311